# How can I create a default constructor c++?

Tags: c++

I'm currently learning how to code object oriented and I've created 2 classes (Applicant and OfferLetter) and trying to inherit those 2 classes into a third class (Software Engineer). I've gotten it structured for the most part however im getting an error code on my compiler that says "No default constructor exists for the class "OfferLetter". What can i do to fix this error?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Applicant{
    private:
        string Name;
        string JobTitle;
        string Degree;
        int YearsOfExpiremce;
        int Age;

    public: 
        //Name 
        void setName(string name){
            Name = name;
        }
        string getName(){
            return Name;
        }
        //JobTitle
        void setJobTitle(string jobtitle){
            JobTitle = jobtitle;
        }
        string getJobTitle(){
            return JobTitle;
        }
        //Degree
        void setDegree(string degree){
            Degree = degree;
        }
        string getDegree(){
            return Degree;
        }
        //Expirence
        void setExpirence(int expirence){
            YearsOfExpiremce = expirence;
        }
        int getExpirence(){
            return YearsOfExpiremce;
        }
        //Age
        void setAge(int age){
            Age = age;
        }
        int getAge(){
            return Age;
        }
            //Constructor
            Applicant(string name, string jobtitle, string degree, int expirence, int age){
                Name = name;
                JobTitle = jobtitle;
                Degree = degree;
                YearsOfExpiremce = expirence;
                Age = age;
            }
};

class OfferLetter{
    private:
        int BaseSalary;
        int SignOnBonus;
        int Stocks;
        int Incentives;

    public:
        //Base Salary
        void setSalary(int salary){
            BaseSalary = salary;
        }
        int getSalary(){
            return BaseSalary;
        }
        //Sign-On Bonus
        void setBonus(int bonus){
            SignOnBonus = bonus;
        }
        int getBonus(){
            return SignOnBonus;
        }
        //Stocks
        void setStocks(int stocks){
            Stocks = stocks;
        }
        int getStocks(){
            return Stocks;
        }
        //Incentives
        void setIncentives(int incentives){
            Incentives = incentives;
        }
        int getIncentives(){
            return Incentives;
        }
            //Constructor
            OfferLetter(int salary, int bonus, int stocks, int incentives){
                BaseSalary = salary;
                SignOnBonus = bonus;
                Stocks = stocks;
                Incentives = incentives;
            }
};

class SoftwareEngineer: public Applicant, public OfferLetter{
    public:
        string ProgrammingLanguage;
        string JobDescription;
       
        SoftwareEngineer(string name, string jobtitle, string degree, int expirence, int age, int salary, int bonus,
                        int stocks, int incentives, string language, string jd)

            :Applicant(name, jobtitle, degree, expirence, age)
            :OfferLetter(salary, bonus, stocks, incentives)
            
        {
            ProgrammingLanguage = language;
            JobDescription = jd;
        }

        void DisplaySEOfferLetter(){
            cout << "Congratulations on your job offer, Here is your total compensation. " << endl;
            cout << "Please respond to us in the next 5 days to confirm your Job Offer." << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Total Compensation " << endl;
            cout << "-------------------" << endl;
            cout << "Role: Software Engineer " << endl;
            cout << "Job Description: $" << endl;
            cout << "Base Salary  : $" << endl;
            cout << "Sign-On Bonus: $" << endl;
            cout << "Stocks       : $" << endl;
            cout << "Incentives   : $" << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
};
```

Comment: This is actually a typo. A constructor initialiser list follows a single `:` that comes before the first entity in the list, and commas before subsequent (after the first) entities.   So replace the `:` before `OfferLetter` with a `,`.  The error message you describe is because what you did has confused your particular compiler - when it encounters the second `:` it deems the initialiser list is complete, so `OfferLetter` will have needed a default constructor (one that accepts no arguments).  Although you haven't given relevant information, there would be more diagnostics after that.

Comment: I know this is a toy example, but OO is not all about inheritance. In practice a Software engineer would not inherit from an offer letter aggregation where he/she might optionally have an OfferLetter. Or there is an Application class, that aggregates both an Engineer and a Letter. (There is a design step beyond this called dependency injection but that's for another time)

Comment: Still in the beginning stages of OOP. I know this is how things aren't really done in practice but im just creating some programs to get an idea of how some concepts work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is not the default constructor missing, but that you have a syntax error in your code:

```
SoftwareEngineer(string name, string jobtitle, string degree,
                 int expirence, int age, int salary, int bonus,
                 int stocks, int incentives, string language, string jd)
    :Applicant(name, jobtitle, degree, expirence, age)
    :OfferLetter(salary, bonus, stocks, incentives)
{
}
```

You attempt to create *two* constructor initializer lists, which is wrong. A constructor have a single *comma-separated* list:

```
SoftwareEngineer(string name, string jobtitle, string degree,
                 int expirence, int age, int salary, int bonus,
                 int stocks, int incentives, string language, string jd)
    : Applicant(name, jobtitle, degree, expirence, age),  // Note comma here
      OfferLetter(salary, bonus, stocks, incentives)      // No colon on this line
{
}
```

---

Note that you can initialize member variables using the initializer list as well, and it's recommended to use that instead of assignment inside the constructor body:

```
SoftwareEngineer(string name, string jobtitle, string degree,
                 int expirence, int age, int salary, int bonus,
                 int stocks, int incentives, string language, string jd)
    : Applicant(name, jobtitle, degree, expirence, age),  // Note comma here
      OfferLetter(salary, bonus, stocks, incentives),      // No colon on this line
      ProgrammingLanguage(language),  // Added initialization
      JobDescription(jd)              // of member variables
{
    // Now this can be totally empty
}
```